# for(){} and setInterval() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to picture 5s change next picture, but I can't make this work.

```
<div class="g-carousel" id="m-carousel">
    <a href="http://open.163.com/" class="pciture" target="_blank"><img src="imag/banner1.jpg" ></a>
    <a href="http://study.163.com/" class="pciture two" target="_blank" style="display:none"><img src="imag/banner2.jpg" ></a>
    <a href="http://www.icourse163.org/" class="pciture three" target="_blank" style="display:none"><img src="imag/banner3.jpg" ></a>
    <div class="button">
        <i class="checked"></i><i></i><i></i>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showpic() {
        var carousel = document.getElementById("m-carousel")
        var pciture = carousel.getElementsByClassName("pciture");
                for (var i=0 ; i < pciture.length; i++)
                    if (i>2) i=0;
                pciture[i].style.display="none";
                pciture[i+1].style.display="block";

        }
        window.onload=function function_name(argument) {
            setInterval("showpic()",5000);
        }   
</script>
```

Comment: I will suggest using one of plenty available jQuery plugins for this.

Comment: check my jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62hughdj/15/)

```
function showpic() {

        var carousel = document.getElementById("m-carousel");
        var carouselLength = carousel.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
        var pciture = carousel.getElementsByClassName("pciture");

        if (i>=carouselLength-1){
              pciture[i].style.display="none";
              i=0;
              pciture[i].style.display="block";
              i--;
         }else{
               pciture[i].style.display="none";
               pciture[i+1].style.display="block";
         }
         i++;           
        }
var i = 0;
setInterval(showpic,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a global counter:

```
var counter = 0;

function showpic() {
    var carousel = document.getElementById("m-carousel")
    var pciture = carousel.getElementsByClassName("pciture");

    // Hide all the pictures.
    for (var i=0 ; i < pciture.length; i++)
    {
        pciture[i].style.display="none";
    }

    // Show the picture based on the counter.
    pciture[counter].style.display="block";

    // Increment the counter ready for next time.
    counter++;

    // Check if the counter needs to loop back.
    if(counter >= pciture.length)
        counter = 0;
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(showpic, 5000);
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/kmen9j15/)

Comment: Just `setInterval(showpic, 5000);` Also manage the `counter` if it is going beyond `length` of the `elements`

Comment: Your code will be increasing `counter` to infinity, are you sure this will work?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it would help if you change

```
window.onload=function function_name(argument) {
```

to

```
window.onload=function(argument) {
```

Hope that helps.

Regards

P.S. Live long and prosper :-)